# how to apply all intention action ( yellow bulb suggestion ) or quick fixes ( red bulb suggestion ) together in android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In my code, there is the same intention suggestion at several lines, FYI "Unnecessary safe call on a non-null receiver".
I need to go to every yellow bulb and apply suggestions to correct the code.

[image: snapshot of android studio code]

Answer (score 0):

Press the right arrow to expand the menu, for some inspections there will be an option to apply to all in file. If it's not available, then this specific inspection has no support for batch fixes.